# ARM internal watchdog reset issue

Tags: arm

The ARM processor watchdog (or the internal watchdog) - Does the watchdog reset trigger immediately after a watchdog counter counts down to 0. Will there be a delay in resetting the processor.

Comment: Are you talking about a MAC OS specific thing here?  I've seen watch dog threads on iOS/MAC stuff, but not on other ARM platforms.  I am by no means an expert here, but if it is an iOS thing, adding that tag will help you get a better answer faster.

Comment: It depends on how that reset is wired in the chip, and where it goes which is specific to the chip vendor not ARM.  ARM sends the watchdog reset out when the timer expires, it is up to the chip vendor to do something with it.